# Making punctuation groups almost unbreakable, avoiding orphans and widows

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation, widows-orphans, penalty

I have a script that generates PDF from the rich text. I want to make sure there are no orphans and widows that contains only punctuations or line break before punctuation if there is a word attached to the punctuation. Let's say we have this sentence:

```
“Oh. Wow.” He frowned. “What? I thought you were teaching…”
```

At the moment is being rendered like this
[image: pdf example]

, but i want it to be rendered more like:

```
“Oh. Wow.” He frowned. “What? I thought you were 
teaching…”
```

or

```
“Oh. Wow.” He frowned. “What? I thought you were teach-
ing…”
```

I actually did a regex that finds the punctuations and puts penalties around them like this

```
“Oh. Wow.” He frowned. “What? I thought you were teaching\penalty900{}…\penalty900{}”\penalty900{}
```

which is quite high penalty and it still refuses to break the line earlier and the result is the same as in the image above. If I increase the penalty to `10000` which is equivalent to `\nobreak` it is actually working, however then I have problem with lines like

1. The line with lot of punctuations

```
Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…Lorem…Ipsum…
```

2. Only dots

```
.................................................................................................................................................................................
```

[image]

In order to fix this I used the regex to split these long punctuations to be the groups of 5 and then added penalty between the group to be `301`, which gives this result

```
.\penalty10000.\penalty10000.\penalty10000.\penalty10000.\penalty301.\penalty10000.\penalty10000.\penalty10000.\penalty10000.
```

I also wrote the regex to find all the ellipsis that are not fallowed by any other punctuation and set the penalty to `301`, so it can break after ellipsis

```
Lorem…Ipsum…
```

would become

```
Lorem…\penalty301{}Ipsum…\penalty301{}
```

Now it kinda works, but the whole regex the strings feels very fragile, so finally the question:

Is it possible to achieve it in more LaTeX way, without all the regEx, like setting some global punctuations list and penalties for them? I also do not understand why the penalty of `900` didn't force latex to actually break the line before the word, as the `\hyphenpenalty=50` then LaTeX theoretically should prefer to hypenize the word instead of breaking after the word.

Comment: It would be easier for us to work with an example … I don't know how “a script that generates PDF from the rich text” actually works, and when and where LaTeX (?) comes into play. That said, there's a package for LuaLaTeX that might be useful: https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-widow-control

Comment: tex would never break a line where you show with standard settings so the fix is to change the code you have not shown. please always provide an example that reproduces the issue you are asking about

Comment: Wow, thank you for so fast response, I sadly cannot share the whole .tex file, however I tried to make some minimum example on overleaf and this is when I realised the pure TeX actually works as i would like it to work. I must have set something somewhere that is breaking it :/. Is there a tool to debug the latex or at least see the penalties in every place?